Vuetify form fails validation but the fields are correct
I have a nuxt (latest) application and I have this this login form so I can log into the back end api. The problem is the validation fails because the form stays invalid. Here is the code for the form:
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-col cols="12" sm="8" md="6">
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title class="text-h5">Login</v-card-title>
          <v-card-subtitle>Enter your credentials to access your account</v-card-subtitle>

          <v-form v-model:valid="valid" ref="form">
            <v-card-text>
              <v-text-field v-model="email" label="Email" type="email" :rules="emailRules" required />
              <v-text-field v-model="password" label="Password" type="password" :rules="passwordRules" required />
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn :disabled="!valid" @click="handleLogin" color="primary" class="ma-2"> Login </v-btn>
              <v-btn @click="navigateToRegister" variant="text" class="ma-2"> Register </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-form>

          <v-alert v-if="error" type="error" dismissible class="ma-2">
            {{ error }}
          </v-alert>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { useAuth } from "~/composables/useAuth";

// router
const router = useRouter();

// login authorization
const { login } = useAuth();

// state
const valid = ref(false);

// refs
const form = ref(null);

// data
const email = ref("");
const password = ref("");
const error = ref<string | null>(null);

// rules
const emailRules = [
  (v: string) => !!v || "Email is required",
  (v: string) => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || "Email must be valid",
];

const passwordRules = [(v: string) => !!v || "Password is required"];

// functions
useHead({
  title: "Login",
  meta: [{ name: "description", content: "Log into your account" }],
  bodyAttrs: {
    class: "login",
  },
  script: [{}],
});

const handleLogin = async () => {
  try {
    await login(email.value, password.value);
    router.push("/dashboard");
  } catch (err) {
    error.value = "Invalid email or password";
  }
};

const navigateToRegister = () => {
  router.push("/register");
};
</script>

Problem is the form stays invalid even if the email is correct and the password is filled in. So if the rules are passed why does the form stay invalid?

valid is not bound to the v-form modelValue here.
You need to replace v-model:valid="valid" with v-model="valid".
In the API Spec of v-form it's stated, that a forms 'default' modelValue, is it's valid state. It's not a special 'valid' modelValue.
